# Firebase get request querying multiple tables

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send  get request to get the information of a row and that of its comments and options (rows, comments, options are all different tables). Currently, the request returns the row and comment info, but an empty array for the options, like so:

```
{
    "categoryId": "Category1",
    "dataType": "Text",
    "approveCount": 0,
    "createdAt": "10:00",
    "body": "testneww",
    "disapproveCount": 0,
    "index": 1,
    "visit": "Both",
    "rowId": "ID",
    "comments": [
        {
            "rowId": "ID",
            "createdAt": "2021-02-28T21:32:52.841Z",
            "body": "test comment"
        }
    ],
    "options": []
}
```

code:

```
exports.getOneRow = (req, res) => {
  let rowData = {};
  db.doc(`/rows/${req.params.rowId}`)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Row not found' });
      }
      rowData = doc.data();
      rowData.rowId = doc.id;
      return db
        .collection('comments')
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .where('rowId', '==', req.params.rowId)
        .get();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      rowData.comments = [];
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        rowData.comments.push(doc.data());
   
      })
      return db
      .collection('options')
      .orderBy('index', 'asc')
      .where('rowId', '==', req.params.rowId)
      .get();
    })
    .then((newData)=>{
      rowData.options = [];
      newData.forEach((newDoc) => {
        rowData.options.push(newDoc.data());
   
      })
      return res.json(rowData);     
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
};
```

I presume I'm making a silly mistake somwhere, or is it not possible to do a request like this? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked, I cant see any differences besides adding the parameters individually in 'rowData.options.push' near the end, however ive been staring at the same code for quite a while so please do let me know if im missing something else.

```
  exports.getOneRow = (req, res) => {
    let rowData = {};
    db.doc(`/rows/${req.params.rowId}`)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          rowData = doc.data();
          rowData.rowId = doc.id
          return db
            .collection("comments")
            .where("rowId", "==", req.params.rowId)
            .get();
        } else{
          return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });

        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        rowData.comments = [];
        data.forEach((doc) => {
          rowData.comments.push(doc.data());
        });
        return db
          .collection("options")
          .where("rowId", "==", req.params.rowId)
          .orderBy("index", "asc")
          .get();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        rowData.options = [];
        data.forEach((doc) => {
          rowData.options.push({
            index: doc.data().index,
            body: doc.data().body,
            rowId: doc.data().rowId,
          });
        });
        return res.json(rowData);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
      });
  };
```